# Creating web application using VS 2015 Update 3 creates with references 1.0.0-rc2-final

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

Creating a web application as ASP.NET Core Web Applicaiton (.NET Framework) creates with most of the references as 1.0.0-rc2-final.

I am using the RTM version of VS 2015 Update 3. Hoping the references to be full version rather than rc2-final.

Are the templates updated properly? Do I need an update for the tools? If needed, where will I get it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.Net Core tooling isn't included in Update 3 so apart from Update 3 you also need to install Web tooling. Go to: https://www.microsoft.com/net/download and download ".NET Core Tooling Preview 2 for Visual Studio 2015" (at the bottom of the page).

Answer (score 1):

Probably going to have to update the project with nuget or by hand this assumes you have installed the SDK Core Preview2 Tooling located here.

[NET Core 1.0 for Visual Studio](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817245)

NB: while the framework has RTM'd the tooling is still in preview status since they are still working on it, hence Preview2 status.

if you have a Global.json file I would also suggest clearing out the entry that says "sdk": {}